# Wanting to add a defining element to a class without changing the class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

So this question may sound really strange but I am needing to add a defining element to my line of code so that in the CSS I can target that element when targeting the class as well. My current code is below.
So what I am needing to do is add something to the class without changing the class name from "right-button". So say if I wanted to code in CSS I would code "this.right-button {}", my question sis where in this line of code can I insert the "this"? I hope this makes sense....

```
 <div id="scroll">
     <a href="mensshoes.php" class="right-button"><img   src="images/scrollright.png"/></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yeah I just fixed that sorry. It wasn't showing in my original question.

Comment: @JaromandaX The code was there, it was just Markdown being stupid, as usual.

Comment: Not to sound harsh, but you might want to try restating that question. I can't tell what you're asking for.

Comment: What do you mean by `"this.right-button"`? `this` isn't a keyword in CSS like in JavaScript...?

Comment: @jmar777 No offense taken. I understand that it sounds confusing because it is confusing for me to try to word. Sorry! I will play around with it in the edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an id and attach the css onto that. 
`<a class="right_button" id="id_name">`
`#id_name {css_stuff: here;}`

The other way may be to just use an inline tag `<a class="right_button" style="{css_stuff:here}">`.

Edit: 
Adding another class like the others mentioned is a good method too, but if you're only adding the CSS to that one element, then I think the ID method is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution was the one that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

add another class?

html

```
 <div id="scroll">
     <a href="mensshoes.php" class="right-button bazinga"><img   src="images/scrollright.png"/></a>
 </div>
```

css

```
a.right-button.bazinga {
}
```

actually, with the simple code shown, in css you target this quite simply

```
#scroll .right-button {
}
```

no need to change HTML at all. #scroll is guaranteed to be unique, and if there's only one .right-button within that div, then you've found your target precisely

Answer (score 0):

An element can have as many classes as you want, separated by spaces, so you don't need to change "the class name", just add an extra class:

```
<div id="scroll">
     <a href="mensshoes.php" class="right-button whatever"><img src="images/scrollright.png"/></a>
</div>
```

You can then specify a CSS rule for all elements with both classes, like so:

```
.whatever.right-button { color: red; }
```

The order doesn't matter:

```
.right-button.whatever { color: red; }
```

JS libraries like jQuery, or the native querySelectorAll, use exactly the same syntax as CSS for matching elements. If you are somehow matching the exact text of the `class` attribute, then you're Doing It Wrong, as that attribute is defined as a space separated list.

Comment: Will doing this effect the javascript that is calling on the class?

Comment: no, it can still be found using `document.querySelector('.right-button')` for instance